# BeatifulSoap find() returns "None" with any name/attributes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get some informations about a product i'm interested in, on Amazon.
I'm using BeatifulSoap library for webscraping :

```
URL = 'https://www.amazon.it/gp/offer-listing/B08KHL2J5X/ref=dp_olp_unknown_mbc'

page = requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
title = soup.find('span',class_='a-size-large a-color-price olpOfferPrice a-text-bold')
print(title)
```

In the pic, the highlined row it's the one i want to select, but when i run my script i get 'None' everytime. (Printing the entire output after BeatifulSoap call, give me the entire HTML source, so i'm using the right URL)
Any solutions?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What's the url?

Comment: Try printing out the soup object to see if it contains what you see in the browser. Often, a site may inject stuff after the fact via JavaScript, so when you download the source locally, it is not present. In cases like this, using something like Selenium may be your best bet to get the dynamic content.

Comment: In the soup object there's the information i need, but it seems that find() method can extract only the "top level" section of the HTML source file. If i try soup.find_all('div') i get only 2 elements : the second one is a big <div>; inside of it there are the entire data of the HTML source i'm trying to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .text() to get the text of an element.

so change:

```
print(title)
```

to:

```
print(title.text)
```

Output:

```
                EUR 1.153,00
```

Comment: Using title.text i get an error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: ```To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com. ``` is what is not allowing you to get the text anymore, you may need to use a different proxy

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use BS alone in this case. You can easily use add Selenium to scrape the website:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.amazon.it/gp/offer-listing/B08KHL2J5X/ref=dp_olp_unknown_mbc'


driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get(url)

html_content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

title = soup.find('span',class_='a-size-large a-color-price olpOfferPrice a-text-bold')

print(title)
```

If you don't can use Safari you have to download the webdriver for Chrome, Firefox etc. but there is plenty of reading material on this topic.